# Variable passing with escape character in ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, escaping, parameter-passing

I am using a PowerShell session to run some commands and want the argument to be passed as is, including quotes like `"`. The command I'm passing does not include the quotes, here is the code:

```
$myarg= "run"
$CArg = "XXX"    ## CArg should be passed as "XXX"

Invoke-Command -Session $session  -Scriptblock { param($myarg,$CArg) &'C:\program.exe'  $myarg  -CArg $CArg -ArgumentList $myarg,$CArg
```

I also tried `@ArgumentList` and had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

For problems like this I usually fall back to using [scriptblock]::create(), and an expandable here-string:

```
$myarg= "run"
$CArg = "XXX"    ## CArg should be passed as "XXX"

$scriptblock = [scriptblock]::create(@"
&'C:\program.exe'  $myarg  -CArg "$CArg"
"@)

 Invoke-Command -Session $session  -Scriptblock $scriptblock
```

The here string lets you put whatever kind  of quotes you want, whereever you want them.

Comment: Can you clarify that?

Comment: I added my solution below, for some reason powershell does not like @ at the beginning of the script, i used to do it in C# to escape \ characters.
in C#:
File.Open(@"C:\program.exe") // this is equivalant to :
File.Open("C:\\program.exe") // these are the same
for powershell this does not work...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "@ is not acceptable in PS", but I suspect you many not be formatting the here-string correctly. In a here-string, the opening @" can be in any position on the line, but the closing "@ must start in position 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the receiving EXE to get the parameter with quotes surrounding it, you have to work at it a bit to defeat the various phases that strip away quotes. Try this:

```
120> $carg = "`"`"`"foo`"`"`""
121> Invoke-Command { param($myarg,$CArg) echoargs $myarg -CArg $CArg } -ArgumentList myarg,$CArg

Arg 0 is <run>
Arg 1 is <-CArg>
Arg 2 is <"foo">

Command line:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PowerShell Community Extensions\Pscx3\Pscx\Apps\EchoArgs.exe"  run -CArg """foo"""
```

Note that echoargs is a utility from [PSCX](http://pcsx.codeplex.com) that helps with debugging parameter passing to native exes.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but if you pass argument as """XXX"""

```
PS C:\Users\demo.b> """XXXX"""
"XXXX"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$CArg = "`"XXX`""
$string = "&'C:\program.exe' $myarg -CArg" +  "$CArg"
$scriptblock = [scriptblock]::create($string)
Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock $scriptblock
```